# Maximum size of an iscsi volume on a debian system

Tags: linux, storage, storage-spaces

We are preparing a new storage infrastructure and are wondering if there is a maximum size limit for ISCSI volumes on Debian.

In our experience, on Windows there is a limit of 16TB for such volumes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open-iSCSI, the Linux iSCSI initiator, doesn't appear to have any built in limits and should support LUNs up to the maximum size of a block device on that particular Linux kernel, which as best I can tell is currently [16 EB](https://access.redhat.com/solutions/1532) (subscription required).

Your storage server is unlikely to be able to provide LUNs this large. For instance NetApp does not support LUNs larger than [16 TB](https://library.netapp.com/ecmdocs/ECMP1196980/html/GUID-E04F9093-66B3-49F6-A349-F4A46F2036C2.html). But LIO, the Linux in-kernel iSCSI target, [claims](https://access.redhat.com/solutions/1532) a "maximum LUN size ¾PB".